# How to webscrape a file which adress changes in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, download, data-mining

I am interested in this excel file, which structure does not change : https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/cc0aed5c-b4fc-440d-9522-18680fb2ef6a

Which i can get from this page : https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count

The last url does not change over time, whereas the first one does.

But I guess the url of the file is located somewhere in the elements of the fixed webpage, even if it is changed, and the the generation of the filename follows a repetitive procedure.

Therefore, is there a way, in R, to get the file (which is updated every week or so) in an automated manner, without dowloading it manually each time ?

Answer (score 2):

You skipped the part of the question where you talk about what you had done. Or searching the web for tutorials. But it was easy to do so here goes. You'll have to look up an rvest tutorial for more explanation.

```
library(rvest) # to allow easy scraping
library(magrittr) # to allow %>% pipe commands

page <- read_html("https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count")

# Find links that match excel type files as defined by the page
links <- page %>%
  html_nodes("span.file--mime-application-vnd-ms-excel-sheet-binary-macroEnabled-12") %>%
  html_nodes("a")

links_df <- data.frame(
  title = links %>% html_attr("title"),
  link = links %>% html_attr("href")
)

links_df
title
# 1              north_america_rotary_rig_count_jan_2000_-_current.xlsb
# 2 north_american_rotary_rig_count_pivot_table_feb_2011_-_current.xlsb
# link
# 1 https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/cc0aed5c-b4fc-440d-9522-18680fb2ef6a
# 2 https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/c7852ea5-5bf5-4c47-b52c-f025597cdddf
```

Comment: I was lost in the developper tool of google chrome, trying to find some json files, so not really close to anything like that. Thanks

Comment: Looking in the network tab for a datafile is a great place to start. There may even be one. But this site is pretty simple and is only one page per day. So it was easier to just find a working html class to identify on the page.